# Javascript NextJS Fetch - Google API "Must specify at least one request"

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create an NextJS application that will automate a google doc based on a team selection.

Plan is, when you click on a button that says "generate report" for that team, it will give you a list of all the players and their stats, like so:

> "PLAYER 1"
>
> | Points | Rebounds | Assists |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12.4 | 4.5 | 5 |

I'm currently having issues with getting the Google Doc API to play ball.

I can successfully make a request, that will create a document in my google drive, however, I am unable to perform a batch update to add even text to the document. I get an error on the network request:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Must specify at least one request.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I've read through the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate), however, I'm not sure of the best way to proceed. Here's my code for the request below:

```
 const createDoc = (teamName: string) => {
    const fileName: string = `${teamName} Scouting Report 2023`;

    const requestBody: any = {
      requests: [
        {
          insertText: {
            text: 'THIS IS A  BIG OLD TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS YA YEET',
            endOfSegmentLocation: {},
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const parsedRequest: any = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

    fetch(`https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents?title=${fileName}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      //   @ts-ignore
      headers: new Headers({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken }),
    })
      .then((res: any) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val.documentId);
        const documentId = val.documentId;
        fetch(
          `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`,
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
              //   @ts-ignore
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken,
            }),
            // @ts-ignore
            payload: JSON.stringify({
              requests: [
                {
                  insertText: {
                    text: 'THIS IS A  BIG OLD TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS YA YEET',
                    endOfSegmentLocation: {},
                  },
                },
              ],
            }),
          },
        );
      })
      .then((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove this issue of `INVALID_ARGUMENT` of `however, I am unable to perform a batch update to add even text to the document. I get an error on the network request:` by modifying your showing script.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
fetch(
  `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      //   @ts-ignore
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken,
    }),
    // @ts-ignore
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      requests: [
        {
          insertText: {
            text: 'THIS IS A  BIG OLD TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS YA YEET',
            endOfSegmentLocation: {},
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  },
);
```

#### To:

```
fetch(
  `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${documentId}:batchUpdate`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      //   @ts-ignore
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session?.accessToken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }),
    // @ts-ignore
    body: JSON.stringify({
      requests: [
        {
          insertText: {
            text: 'THIS IS A  BIG OLD TEST TO SEE IF THIS WORKS YA YEET',
            endOfSegmentLocation: {},
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  },
);
```

#### Refererence:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've now run into another issue though.

Here's the raw error I get:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Must specify at least one request.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

And the console.error: 
{
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers(7) { "cache-control" → "private", "content-encoding" → "gzip", "content-length" → "125", … }
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/__docid__:batchUpdate"

Comment: @Matthew Dwyer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I've now run into another issue though.`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?